# How to export csv with title above headers in r

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have a csv-file that looks like this:

[image]

In order for the file to work with an annoying third-party application it's absolutely vital that it looks like this instead, with at title above the variable headings:

[image]

That is to say like this if we edit the file with notepad:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) from a data.frame**

```
df_formatted <- rbind(c("title", rep(NA, ncol(df) - 1)), names(df), df)

readr::write_csv2(df_formatted, "test.csv", col_names = FALSE, na = "")
```

**some sample data**

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:3], col2 = 1:3, col3 = 2:4, col4 = 3:5)
```

**2) adding to an existing csv file**

```
fileConn <- file("test.csv")
writeLines(c("title;;;", readLines(fileConn)), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

**"in notepad"**

```
title;;;
col1;col2;col3;col4
a;1;2;3
b;2;3;4
c;3;4;5
```

Comment: Okay, I made it work using the writelines method, only it messes up my encoding a bit (usually i export via write_excel_csv2) so that programs such as excel can understand my scandinavian characters.

Is there a quick fix for this of whould I pose another question?

Comment: When you you use `readLines`, make sure you set the right encoding, assuming your existing csv files are in `UTF-8` then use `writeLines(c("title;;;", readLines(fileConn, encoding = "UTF-8")), fileConn)`